# What is the difference between mamdani and sugeno in fuzzy logic?

Tags: fuzzy-logic

I realise that the difference lies in the way the defuzzification happens but I don't fully understand it. I've read some papers comparing the outputs from the two models but I'm still not really sure how they are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> These are the primary differences between Mandani FIS and Sugeno FIS:

**Mamdani FIS**

- Output membership function is present
- Crisp result is obtained through defuzzification of rules’ consequent
- Non-continuous output surface
- MISO (Multiple Input Single Output) and MIMO (Multiple Input Multiple Output) systems
- Expressive power and Interpretable rule consequents
- Less flexibility in system design

**Sugeno FIS**

- No output membership function is present
- No defuzzification: crisp result is obtained using weighted average of the rules’ consequent
- Continuous output surface
- Only MISO systems
- Loss of interpretability
- More flexibility in system design

Answer (score 4):

Mamdani- It entails a substantial computational burden.
Sugeno - It is computationally efficient.
Mamdani- It is well suited to human input.
Sugeno- It its well suited to mathematically analysis.

Comment: Thanks, been watching this for a while and no-one summarized it quite so succinctly.

Answer (score 3):

Mamdani type fuzzy inference gives an output that is a fuzzy set. Sugeno-type inference gives an output that is either constant or a linear (weighted) mathematical expression.

e.g Mamdani: If A is X1, and B is X2, then C is X3.   (X1, X2, X3 are fuzzy sets).

Sugeno: If A is X1 and B is X2 then C = ax1 + bx2 + c (linear expression) (a,b,and c are constants)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).